# Mouse performance on VMWare Workstation Player 14

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I need to improve performance of mouse movement on guest OS, it is Windows XP Professional.
I'm referring to the [link](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1033416?language=en_US) and I cannot see the settings in Workstation Player 14.

[image]

Comment: The settings you reference apply to Workstation Pro, not to Player.  That said, [the "Optimize mouse for games" setting is not about mouse *performance*, it's about how the mouse *behaves*](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-53BB2D29-9ADA-4028-B8F0-FD6905F37762.html).  For example, in a first-person shooter, you would want mouse movement to change your orientation, not to cause the mouse cursor to leave the VM.  Exactly what problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install VMware tools [Installing VMware Tools in VMware Player (1035392)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1035392?language=en_US). Or if it is a option get a copy of VMware workstation.